# Controlling the camera during combat

Tags: infinity-blade-2

Some times, during combat, it gets really hard to see the enemy because the camera suddenly moves right behind the main character. This makes fighting nearly impossible for me.

At first, I thought it was just part of the challenge, but it seems rather silly that blocking the view with the player character would be intentional. So I think I might be doing something wrong.

Is there a way to move the camera around during combat? Regular one finger dragging simply makes the character attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't control the camera during combat. I always assumed that it was in part to keep things challenging, but it also keep things from getting boring during a long fight, with the view changing a few times as you take down more health of your opponent.